# Adding pairs to a vector C++

Tags: c++, loops, vector, boolean, std-pair

So, I'm attempting to add pairs to a vector, but they must successfully pass 2 criteria:

1. Their weight or 2nd value is greater than or equal to zero. and throws a string error if it does.
2. The vector must not already contain the key or the first value

It specifically must be done while the function returns a void type, however for some reason, this logic doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions?

```
void add(KEY_T key, WEIGHT_T weight)
    {
        bool contains = false;

        if (weight < 0)
        {

            std::cout << "ERROR, invalid weight" << std::endl; //Throw error.
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < _valueToWeightMap.size(); x++)
        {
            if (_valueToWeightMap[x].first == key)
            {
                contains = true;
            }
        }

        if (weight > 0 && contains == false)
            {

            _valueToWeightMap.push_back(std::make_pair(key, weight));

            }

        }
```

Here is the main:

```
int main()
{
    DiscreteDistribution<std::string> dist1;

    dist1.add("Helmet", -1);
    dist1.add("Gloves", 5);
    dist1.add("Gloves", 5);
    dist1.add("cloud", 8);
```

For some reason, I'm not getting an error when I try to add Helmet as -1. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use a `std::map<std::string, int>`? Then `values[key] = weight;`

Comment: 1) `cout` doesn't throw an error, as your comment suggests. It just outputs the string to the console. The rest of the function is executed anyways. Did you want to throw an exception? 2) What is `WEIGHT_T`? Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Why don't you use an unsigned weight type?

Comment: _logic doesn't seem to be working_ whatever that means. What is DiscreteDistribution?

Comment: Rather than setting `contains` true, you could just return.  That way you don't need to test `contains`.  You don't add the key / weight if weight is zero.  Just get rid of the final test on `weight`.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
        std::cout << "ERROR, invalid weight" << std::endl; //Throw error.
```

does not do what the comment says (throw an error).  This line:

```
        throw "ERROR, invalid weight"; //Throw error.
```

does.  However, I ***strongly*** recommend that you only ever throw exceptions derived from `std::exception`.  This:

```
        throw std::range_error("ERROR, invalid weight"); //Throw error.
```

is **much** better.